# Push Notification in production is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I Have implemented [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) url.

Development mode notification is working but in production its not working. and shows errors.

```
  dakshas-iMac:alootamatar daksha$ php push_demo.php

  Warning: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/push_demo.php on line 18

 Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push-apple.com:2195 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) in /Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/push_demo.php on line 18
 Failed to connect: 0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
 iMac:alootamatar daksha$ php push_demo.php

 Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file `/Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/cert.pem' in /Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/push_demo.php on line 18

Warning: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle in /Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/push_demo.php on line 18

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/push_demo.php on line 18

 Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Users/daksha/Desktop/alootamatar/push_demo.php on line 18
 Failed to connect: 0 


  After using APNS tester got response 
  2016-01-01 09:37:08 +0000: Set SSL connection 
  2016-01-01 09:37:08 +0000: Set peer domain name gateway.push.apple.com 
  2016-01-01 09:37:08 +0000: Keychain Opened  
  2016-01-01 09:37:08 +0000: Certificate  data  for Apple Production IOS Push Services: com.daksha.alootamatar initialized successfully 
  2016-01-01 09:37:08 +0000: Sec Identity created 
  2016-01-01 09:37:08 +0000: Client certificate created 
  2016-01-01 09:37:10 +0000: Connected 
  2016-01-01 09:37:10 +0000: Token: <f65ed342 4416c0bf e2a8c26a f3eb9a69 70780771 4eadb033 61ca8aec c28d454a> 
  2016-01-01 09:37:10 +0000: Written 92 bytes sending data to gateway.push.apple.com:2195 

  2016-01-01 09:37:10 +0000: Disconnected from server gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

Comment: according to your url , tutorials works well..try again to create cirtificates and pem file.

Comment: you are using production certificate ?

Comment: Did you use the correct Passphrase for production ??

Comment: my suggestion is, please read carefully tutorial and apply it will defiantly work fine because i also implemented in my live app.

Comment: I have done the things and working well when I have tested the app before in development mode. But the production is not working and also I have followed the 2 - 3 times same steps.

Comment: I have done all the steps again and when tested the certificate for production mode in Terminal message printed " Notification sent successfully" but not received in device and uploaded the new version for live url and waiting.

Comment: Finally I follow the same steps again and now its working when sending message using Terminal. But when sending notification from live server the connection Time out error shown.

Comment: I changed the server now its working. May be issue is with the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure you install production APN certificates on your server, not development certificates.

After that make sure, you are sending the notification to right server URL

- Sandbox: `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`, port `2195`. (for
  thedevelopment)
- Production: `gateway.push.apple.com`, port `2195`. (for    the release)

Still you have the same problem, try this App. [APN Tester](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have used the production certificate and  posted on this url ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195. Also try to APN Tester and their response we update in question.