# gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ios, push-notification, sandbox

Apple push notification is not working in sandbox. I tried to connect in terminal for sandbox by this command `telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195` but it through this error `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.

If I connect with `telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195` its connected and I'm getting something like this below,

```
Trying 17.188.147.165...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
```

There is no issue with APNS certificates. Its working fine if i install with some other server(my friend server in different country).

I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554680/push-notification-in-production-is-not-working

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried this already but for me sandbox is not working