# IOS not getting Push Notifications in production environment

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I am tired of looking for the problem, I am not getting Push Notifications in production environment after uploading to App store.
I tried all possible ways i heard on the net but with no chance
I am getting the below error in APNS:

10:06:09: preparing to send payload...
10:06:09: trying to connect....
10:06:09: Connected....
10:06:10: Sent & Disconnected....!
10:06:20: None (unknown)
and sometimes I am getting (Invalid Token)

Push Notifications is working very well on developer mode, but not working at all when archiving it.

On other hand below is my AppDelegate code:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var settings: UNNotificationSettings?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // iOS 10 support

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                          name:   NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
 return true
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
```

func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error)
    }

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Let FCM know about the message for analytics etc.
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.


    // Print full message.
    print("userInfo: \(userInfo)")

    completionHandler(.noData)
}
func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

        guard granted else { return }
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}
func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue:     UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
}
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        // Subscribe to a topic after got a FCM Registration token
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/coffee")
    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted      before having a token.
    connectToFCM()
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFCM() {
    Messaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFCM()
}

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    Messaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push Notification in production is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554680/push-notification-in-production-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check **PHP** side for Push notification.Production environment you can't check push notification at your side, you need to trigger from server side -

**Development Server -**

`ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

**Production Server -**

`ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

---

if you will face any issue with the port you can try with -

- 2195
- 2196

---

**More details -** [Check this link](http://codular.com/sending-ios-push-notifications-with-php)

Comment: Welcome. @Sandy